# Paginating with kaminari on a custom route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, kaminari

I'm having a problem with kaminari, it doesn't seem to be able to paginate results when using a custom "unRestful" url.

```
resources :provinces, :path => '', :only => [ :show ] do
  resources :sports, :only => [ :show ] do
    match ':page', :controller => 'facilities', :action => 'index'
  end
end
```

So, /:foo/sports/:bar points to a controller, /:foo/sports/:bar/1 points to another 1. It's a disgusting URL scheme but I don't have the leverage right now to change the specs.

If I call the page without Kaminari, everything works as expected, I see the first page. When I use Kaminari like:

```
<%= paginate @facilities, :params => { :controller => 'facilities', :action => 'index' } %>
```

Rails gives me a routing error on the following URL:

```
http://lvh.me:8080/milano/sports/palestra/1

No route matches {:controller=>"facilities", :province_id=>"milano", :sport_id=>"palestra", :page=>nil}
```

I honestly don't know what to do, everything seems right to me, and couldn't find a kaminari group or more documentation on my case.

The problem seems to be that the call to paginate somewhat generates a URL with page set to nil...

Any suggestion?

Using rails (3.2.8)
Using kaminari (0.14.0)

Comment: Could you try page as query parameter, to debug into more details. This problem does not seems to be with kaminari but rails

Answer (score 0):

in controller

```
 @facilities = kaminari.paginate_array(@facilities).page(params[:page]).per(params[:per_page])
```

and in your view `<%= page_entries_info @facilities %>` & `<%= paginate @facilities %>`